# What to do with a poor question that I already know the answer to

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Unix & Linux Stack Exchange post: [Kickstart netinstall ignores kickstart file hosted in LAN and proceeds with manual installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481990/kickstart-netinstall-ignores-kickstart-file-hosted-in-lan-and-proceeds-with-manu)

The automatic installation of OS wouldn't work, it turned out that the problem was simply kickstart file not including all necessary options. Should I remove this question or answer it? The problem was very basic .For some reason I just didn't check it even though that should be probably the first thing to do. So I don't think this question will be helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it could be useful to have an answer to this question :-).  I don't see it as a problem.

I appreciate when people can write an answer in the expected format, and not leave the question hanging.  It sounds like you are able to answer it without too much additional effort.

I.e., I think it could be useful to have your explanation, that when a kickstart is missing some options, you won't see an error, but you will still see a manual install screen.  I can imagine I would be confused by that!

If a question was extremely poor by our standards, you would expect to see at least one close vote or down vote.  And if multiple people have asked the same "simple" question, we are able to mark them as duplicates.

---

There is one other potential issue with the question though.  The question concerns a particular kickstart file, which you have hosted on an external site.  This site might go out of business.  At least on StackOverflow, you are required to copy all your code in to the body of the question.  (You can also upload images to embed in your question or answer and illustrate the point, this will use officially endorsed hosting)

The kickstart code isn't obscenely long.  I suggest you just copy it into the question.

Comment: Hey I will answer the question and attach all that information into the body of the question but I would need some guidance on how to do it properly. I couldn't get the formatting to work due to `#` making the next line **bold**.

Comment: @PowerBossNautilus there's a code-formatting button that looks like `{}`

Comment: I am aware of that button and that it's possible to mark code with ``. The problem is that it actually doesn't work for my kickstart file contents. I'll attach a screenshot-https://i.imgur.com/0nPPnKe.png. Only the first line is seen as `code`. I also tried prefixing and suffixing the text with `. Same result.

Comment: @PowerBossNautilus you select the code before pressing the button.  The button indents the code - adds 4 spaces at the start of each line - which makes it a code block in markdown formatting.  Since you asked for help with this, I've applied my suggestion as an edit.

Comment: I managed to install the system using kickstart, I found exactly which parameters were preventing the installation and ways to correct that + some lazy workarounds. I'm ready to post the answer. I need guidance with one more thing: every comment under that question is related to me probably not having network defined, no network connectivity etc. which turned out to have absolutely nothing to do with the issue as the network is working fine. The only flaw is bad kickstart file. What to do with these comments since it appears that they would be just wasting time of a potential reader.

Comment: @PowerBossNautilus excellent question. If you can write a complete question and answer, but the comments would become outdated, you can hopefully use the flag button on the first outdated comment. (grey button on the left side of the comment). You then get to specify a reason, "out of date" is one reason, or you can explain it in a few words if you click "other".  I've flagged a couple of times on other people's answers where old comments have got in the way, and the moderators generally agreed with me.  Comments are secondary on this site, it's expected that they can be deleted quite easily.

Comment: I posted the answer. I flagged the oldest comment that every other comment is a consequence of. If it will get removed will all the others follow aswell? It is offtopic but I can't create meta posts not related to my question yet.